# Mono WebBrowser control on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono, webbrowser-control

I'm writing an application that I would like to have run under either Windows or Linux. Since it is a text application, the obvious choice for rendering and user interaction is to use html in a `WebBrowser` control. This all works great using Mono in Windows, but I'm absolutely stumped on how to get it to work using Mono in Linux. I'm running Linux Mint 17, have MonoDevelop and Firefox installed. The following code snippet compiles and runs, but when the application launches, `wbMain` does not show up. The application dies when trying to render an html string using `wbMain`.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Panel pnlMain;
private Mono.WebBrowser.IWebBrowser wbMain;
private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnGo;

this.pnlMain = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
this.wbMain = Mono.WebBrowser.Manager.GetNewInstance();
this.wbMain.Activate();
this.btnGo = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
this.pnlMain.SuspendLayout();
this.SuspendLayout();
// 
// pnlMain
// 
this.pnlMain.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.wbMain.Window);
this.pnlMain.Controls.Add(this.btnGo);
this.pnlMain.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 1);
this.pnlMain.Name = "pnlMain";
this.pnlMain.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(260, 248);
this.pnlMain.TabIndex = 0;
// 
// wbMain
// 
this.wbMain.Resize(260, 216);
```

Comment: Have you tried using `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` instead of `Mono.WebBrowser.IWebBrowser`?

Comment: Yes. Windows.Forms.WebBrowser works fine on Windows but does not render in Linux. Hence the attempt to use the Mono widget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
this.wbMain = Mono.WebBrowser.Manager.GetNewInstance();
```

The problem lies with your `GetNewInstance()` from what I understand here. `GetNewInstance` assumes platform of Windows by default, you need to pass in your own `Mono.WebBrowser.Platform` for it to render in the framework you want (like Gtk).

[Source Code](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/7223568/)

You can see in the source code I linked, the default `GetNewInstance()` returns `Platform.Winforms`;

```
    public static IWebBrowser GetNewInstance ()
    {
        return Manager.GetNewInstance (Platform.Winforms);
    }
```

Also Mono.WebBrowser has been retired in favor of WebkitSharp. You really should be using WebkitSharp to do this now. WebkitSharp has had...some issues, so there's a currently open version of it called [open-webkit-sharp](https://code.google.com/p/open-webkit-sharp/) that may work for you as well. The code on there is at least up to date as of 2012. Whereas Mono WebBrowser and webkit-sharp haven't had any major code changes...in years, at least 5 to 7 years.

I've also had good luck with the open version of [Awesomium](http://awesomium.codeplex.com/), and it's a staple of the gaming industry. Again, the open version of Awesomium hasn't had any major updates since 2012 though. However, you can get the paid version of Awesomium if money/cost isn't an issue and that has had recent updates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried open webkit sharp, but was dissuaded by the author's note that this was yet another abandoned .net binding of webkit. IOW I don't want to get started with a dead end library. Your remark about Awesomium and the gaming industry gives me some incentive to look there.

Comment: Is this post still relevant in 2020?